# Exporting a Shell Variable From the Command Line

Tags: bash, duplicity

I'm playing around with duplicity via a script that looks like this:

```
export PASSPHRASE=SomeLongGeneratedHardToCrackKey
duplicity /etc scp://FtpUserID@ftp.domain.com/etc
unset PASSPHRASE
```

Here's a [link to the ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto).

If I want to set the PASSPHRASE from the command line instead of setting it from the script how do I do that?

I tried (Via the command line):

```
PASSPHRASE='SomeLongGeneratedHardToCrackKey'

export -n PASSPHRASE
```

However this does not work.  Duplicity still asks me to enter the passphrase for the gpg key.

Thoughts?
TIA,

Ole

Comment: Lose the `-n` (see (`help export`) for details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shells are designed so that scripts and interactive command line sessions look the same. That means that you can effectively retype:

```
export PASSPHRASE=SomeLongGeneratedHardToCrackKey
duplicity /etc scp://FtpUserID@ftp.domain.com/etc
unset PASSPHRASE
```

Since exporting for variables for a particular command only is common, there's a shortcut for it:

```
PASSPHRASE=SomeLongGeneratedHardToCrackKey \
duplicity /etc scp://FtpUserID@ftp.domain.com/etc
```

`export -n` doesn't work because `export -n` is the opposite of `export` as `help export` explains:

```
 ...
  -n    remove the export property from each NAME
 ...
```

Comment: `FOO=bar mycmd args` would not make `FOO` an environment variable; it just restricts the variable in this particular line. It is the same as `FOO=bar`, `mycmd args` and then `unset FOO`. To export it for `mycmd` (`duplicity` here), use [`env`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html), like `env FOO=bar mycmd args`.

Comment: @FranklinYu `FOO=bar mycmd args` will absolutely make `FOO`  an environment variable restricted to `mycmd`.  You don't need `env` for that.

Comment: @FranklinYu `printf '%s\n' "#!/bin/bash" "declare -p FOO" > printfoo && chmod +x printfoo && FOO=bar ./printfoo`  will give you `declare -x FOO="bar"`. If that `-x` isn't proof enough to you `FOO=bar env |grep FOO` should be. If this syntax didn't use environment variables it, would be restricted to shell functions and builtins because there's no way that an non-environment variable would get to an `exec`ed process.

Comment: thank you for your hint. I just verified that you are correct about that; `FOO=bar mycmd args` and `env FOO=bar mycmd args` seems exactly the same. I guess the only advantage of using `env` would be that `-i` of `env` can erase all inherited environment variables. Sorry for posting comments without verifying.